# Overwrite previously declared TypeScript function

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my IDE all of the `.ts` TypeScript files are compiled into a single file. This includes my unit test files. This allows me to have type checking in my tests and a build all in one step. However, when I boot my dev server it cannot find the jasmine method `describe()` so I'm overloading it if it's not defined.

```
// If jasmine functions are not defined (i.e. not running tests) skip functions
if (describe === undefined) {
  var describe = (function () { // Duplicate identifier 'describe'
    return function (description: string, callback: () => void) { return }
  })();
}
```

And in jasmine.d.ts

```
declare function describe(description: string, specDefinitions: () => void): void;
```

The issue is TypeScript correctly recognizes that I'm redefining an existing function but I'm intending to do this (hence the `if (describe === undefined)`).

#### Question:

Is there a way to suppress this error? I think I'm looking for some thing like a `function describe() implements jasmine.describe` but as far as I can tell this is only available for classes.

*Note: I'm using TypeScript 1.4*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the global object.

If the code is executed in a browser:

```
window['describe'] = /* ... */
```

Or with Node.js:

```
global['describe'] = /* ... */
```

Alternatively, you can use `eval`.

Comment: I went with the window['describe'] and that seemed to allow both tests and running the application. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple fix is to edit `jasmine.d.ts` to comment out the describe function declaration. The disadvantage of this is that you are editing a library definition and you will have to redo this every time you update the definition file.